# How do I configure nginx to remove a part of the URI given to index.php

Tags: nginx, routes

The routing script of my application expects the URI to be

```
/api/v0/create
```

My request goes to

```
http://my-server.test/subdir/api/v0/create
```

How can I configure nginx to remove the "/subdir" from the URI, providing the expected path to the application's router?

I tried this one, but got only "404 File not found" from the server (not the app):

```
location /subdir/api/ {
    rewrite ^/subdir(.*)$ $1 last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /subdir/api/public/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Without the `rewrite` part I get a 404 from my application.

Thank you for helping!